# Problems computing the Fibonacci Sequence using custom CPU

Tags: assembly

Not sure if this is even the right site to post this in, if it isn't please tell me where I'm supposed to post this.

This is supposed to output 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 but instead it just gets stuck in a loop. I have *no idea* why this is happening, the loop checks if the index is < 20, so I don't understand why it gets stuck in said loop.

- Code:

```
  ; Macros for registers
  $MACRO AX : 0
  $MACRO BX : 1
  $MACRO CX : 2
  $MACRO DX : 3

  ; Load first 2 values
  MVDR 1, AX
  MVDR 1, BX

  ; Set loop index to 0
  MVDR 0, CX

  ; Add the values
  ADD AX, BX
  
  ; Load result into RAM
  MVRAD AX, CX

  ; Set up pointers for the numbers to add
  MVRR CX, DX
  DEC DX

  ; Put the (pointed?) values into AX and BX
  MVARD CX, AX
  MVARD DX, BX

  ; Increment loop index
  INC CX
  
  ; Jump to the start if loop index < 20
  CPRD CX, 20
  JILT 3

  ; Output first 5 values
  MVAR 0, CX
  OUT CX, 0

  MVAR 1, CX
  OUT CX, 0

  MVAR 2, CX
  OUT CX, 0

  MVAR 3, CX
  OUT CX, 0

  MVAR 4, CX
  OUT CX, 0
```

- Code run through custom emulator (execution flow):

```
0 : MVDR, 1 0
1 : MVDR, 1 1
2 : MVDR, 0 2
3 : ADD, 0 1
4 : MVRAD, 0 2
5 : MVRR, 2 3
6 : DEC, 3
7 : MVARD, 2 0
8 : MVARD, 3 1
9 : INC, 2
10 : CMPRD, 2 20
11 : JILT, 3
4 : MVRAD, 0 2
5 : MVRR, 2 3
6 : DEC, 3
7 : MVARD, 2 0
8 : MVARD, 3 1
9 : INC, 2
10 : CMPRD, 2 20
11 : JILT, 3
[Repeats loop indefinitely]
```

- Instruction Set (if I should post this as a link/should clarify stuff, please tell me):

```
0x00 NOOP                   ; Does nothing
0x01 MVRR <REG0> <REG1>     ; Move data from <REG0> to <REG1> (does not clear source register)
0x02 MVDR <DATA> <REG>      ; Move data from <DATA> to <REG> (effectively sets the data in <REG> to <DATA>)
0x03 MVAR <ADDR> <REG>      ; Move data from <ADDR> to <REG> (does not clear source address)
0x04 MVRA <REG> <ADDR>      ; Move data from <REG> to <ADDR> (does not clear source register)
0x05 MVARD <REG_ADDR> <REG> ; Move data from <REG_ADDR> to <REG> (does not clear source address)
0x06 MVRAD <REG> <REG_ADDR> ; Move data from <REG> to <REG_ADDR> (does not clear source register)
0x07 PSHR <REG>             ; Push <REG> to the stack
0x08 PSHD <DATA>            ; Push <DATA> to the stack
0x09 POPR <REG>             ; Pop data off the stack into <REG>
0x0A ADD <REG0> <REG1>      ; Adds <REG0> to <REG1> and stores the result in <REG0>
0x0B SUB <REG0> <REG1>      ; Subtracts <REG0> from <REG1> and stores the result in <REG0>
0x0C OUT <REG> <DATA>       ; Outputs <REG> on port <DATA>
0x0D IN <REG> <DATA>        ; Waits for input on port <DATA>, then stores the value in <REG>
0x0E JMPR <REG>             ; Jumps to address <REG>
0x0F JMPD <DATA>            ; Jumps to address <DATA>
0x10 CMP <REG0> <REG1>      ; Compare <REG0> to <REG1>
0x11 CPRD <REG> <DATA>      ; Compare <REG> to <DATA>
0x12 JINE <DATA>            ; Jumps to address <DATA> if the previous CMP result was !=
0x13 JIEQ <DATA>            ; Jumps to address <DATA> if the previous CMP result was ==
0x14 JIGT <DATA>            ; Jumps to address <DATA> if the previous CMP result was >
0x15 JILT <DATA>            ; Jumps to address <DATA> if the previous CMP result was <
0x16 INC <REG>              ; Increment <REG>
0x17 DEC <REG>              ; Decrement <REG>
```

Comment: The emulator trace does not match the source. For example, line 6 says `DEC, 3` but I don't see that in the source. No idea about your architecture but make sure you are not overwriting the code itself with the result data. Also look at the trace after it should have stopped, so after like 20 iterations. Looking at the loop while it should be looping is pretty pointless.

Comment: One debugging tip is to get it working with the lowest possible limit count, so instead of going 20, go just 1; then when that's working go 2, etc..

Comment: As Jester says, during debugging you need to look at memory to see where it is writing the results -- that's critical.  You can't tell how memory is being updated from that trace.

Comment: @Jester Oops, I forgot to update it, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Jester Overwriting code with data is entirely impossible here, the code is stored in ROM & is completely separate from data.

Comment: @ErikEidt 1: I just tried setting the index limit to 2, it didn't affect anything. 2: I'll see if I can get the emulator to output RAM and registers, but that'll take a bit to get working

Comment: Are you translating working C or pseudo code?  If not, get that working first (its only about 3-5 lines of code), then the rest is just an assembly translation for each little bit of the C code.

Comment: @ErikEidt Neither. The language is fully custom ASM, so I guess I'll convert it to equivalent C code, then convert back.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out -- It was actually my CPU and not my code. The CPRD instruction never reset the CMP flags, so the JILT instruction just jumped every time... How I managed to forget to do that, I don't know.